# "matrix representation of the gradient"

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, differential-geometry, partial-derivative, matrix-calculus

I'm reading a paper and they say "it's convenient to employ a matrix representation for the gradient of *f* ". Then they simply give the matrix form, but obviously I'm a bit lost. Here are the equations shown in the paper

$ f:(x,t) \mapsto (z,t)=f(x,t) $

$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,t)} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\\0^T&1\end{bmatrix}$

I don't know if showing the math helps, but what do they mean by "matrix representation of the gradient"? The bottom row of the matrix they've shown has me confused.

Comment: $f$ is a function from where to where?

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud I edited the mapping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient of $f = (f_1,f_2)$ is given by
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial(x,t)} =\pmatrix{\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x}\\ \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial t}&\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial t}}.$$
Using $f_1 = z$ and $f_2 = t$, you get the result.

Comment: I'm guessing they transpose for reasons later? In the form you show, obviously $ \frac {\partial t}{\partial t} = 1 $ and $ \frac {\partial t}{\partial x} = 0 $ since time does not depend on x. Transposing your matrix, they match :)

Comment: Also, I'm new to mappings and their derivatives...if I were to try and find more info about this, what kind of text would help? Obviously, coming here is a great help, but I would like to learn more. Thanks again

Comment: @ThatsRightJack I don't really see why they transpose it, as that should be a scalar (at least from your question)... As for how to differentiate etc., you can try with books of real analysis (aka calculus, I think). What you should keep in mind is that the derivative of a function $f$ at a point $x$ is the linear map $Df_x$ which gives the best approximation of the form $f(x+h) \approx f(x) + Df_xh$, then you can often build your intuition from there.

Comment: Thanks for your help!!! You've saved me hours of banging my head on the wall : )

Answer (score 2):

For the vector-valued function $$z=f(x)$$ the Jacobian matrix $J$ is defined such that $$dz=J\,dx$$ In other words
$$\eqalign{
 J &= \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \begin{bmatrix}\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial z_1}{\partial x_2}\\\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial z_2}{\partial x_2}\end{bmatrix} \cr\cr
}$$
The paper you're reading refers to $J$ as the gradient, which is true, from a certain perspective.